# Nancy stateless auth not triggering on multiple concurrent request

Tags: c#, angular, nancy

I have a self-hosted Nancy application running with stateless auth.
I also have an angular 4.x app running 3 requests at the same time on this api, different endpoint but same header (same `Authorization` token etc....).

The 3 targeted endpoint  :

`api/v2/vnos/{idVno:Guid}/vnos`

`api/v2/vnos/{idVno:Guid}/distributors`

`api/v2/vnos/{idVno:Guid}/final-users`

My current Bootstrapper auth config :

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
{

    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);

    VnoAppDAO appDao = container.Resolve<VnoAppDAO>();

    StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration configuration = new StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration(ctx =>
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization))
        {
            Response response = new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };
            return null;
        }

        var returned = appDao.GetVnoAppFromToken(ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization).Fold(() =>
        {
            logger.Debug("Didn't find user for {0} Token", ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization);
            return null;
        }, (vnoapp) =>
        {

            App app;
            if (vnoapp.IdVno == new Guid("f968e957-1b4c-4a21-a09f-459e80dcf91c"))
            {
                return app = new App(vnoapp.Name, vnoapp.IdVno, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return app = new App(vnoapp.Name, vnoapp.IdVno);
            }
        });

        logger.Debug("Type returned when auth = {0}", returned.UserName);
        ctx.CurrentUser = returned;
        return (IUserIdentity)returned;

    });

    StatelessAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, configuration);
}
```

And here the logs my apps provide :

[image]

So what we can see here is that at the first try, all my request worked, but when I resend them 2 of them failed (nothing appear in the `curentUser` log which are in the modules before pipelines) and the two exceptions I get are thrown by the before pipelines in modules since the request didn't pass the authentication, they have no claims and they get rejected).

I can't get why those request don't always get through nancyFx auth.

**Edit :** Auth logic works as the following :

If the `Authorization` header is empty response will be `401` (Unauthorized)

If it's not empty it'll check if it can find in database who's making the request with the provided token. If it doesn't find anything it'll log "Didn't find user for [...]" else it will return the object found in database.(Which should be set as the currentUser in context)

Comment: Try adding the auth config in RequestStartup. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest simplifying your logic. It screams over complication to new eyes.

Comment: I already tried in requestStartup, still got the same result, I'll explain a bit more in an edit.